# How Do i Check Whether my android App is encrypted

Tags: android, android-studio

How Do i Check Whether my android App is encrypted? And if so, can I use the encrypted code in another apk class file

Comment: you don't need to check it. If you have encrypted it - then it is encrypted.

Comment: oh,ok, but can you also help me on how to use encrypted code in another apk class file. pls

Comment: how have you encrypted it?